# How a pc host issue long pcie read/write burst to my device?

Tags: dma, pci-e

I have a pcie board with a segment of memory which is mapped to system address space.
The memory controller can accept long burst read or write request.
In the host program, when I use for loop to read or write the memory, will the host generate burst pcie read/write requests to my board automatically?
If not, how the host will issue long burst requests?

regards

Xiang Chao

Answer (score 0):

No, the host can not generate burst PCIe read/write requests to the board.

And it is not good practice to read device memory with for loop. Because the non-posted operations, such as read PCIe memory and R/W configuration space, is quite slow.

**Bus mastering** DMA will be the solution.